# Nested populate in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

How can I do model.populate in Mongoose, when the objects that I want to import are nested in the other schema?

I have these two schemas:

```
const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  eventName: {
    type: String,
  },
 targetAudience: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
      ref: "setting",
    },
  ] }

const settingSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    settingData : [
        {
            icon: {
                type: String,
                require: true
            },
            name: {
                type: String,
                require: true
            } 
        }
    ]}
```

In the settingSchema one of the documents is:

```
{ name: Audience, 
SettingData: [{ icon:AAA, name:audience1}, {icon:BBB, name:audience1}, icon:CCC, name:audience3]}
```

As you see in the schema, for any event there is an array called targetAudience which includes the IDs of the appropriate audiences for this specific event.

When I do events.findOne() I want the targetAudience Array to be populate with the Audience objects. I tried to do that, but it returns an empty array.

```
const res = await eventsData.findOne(filter).populate({
    path: 'targetAudience',
    populate: {path: 'settingData'}
  });
```

I tried to write the populate in several ways, but nothing worked. I read some questions for the same problem in Stack Overflow, but nothing worked. I read the mongoose doc about populate, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Try removing the second populate. Do you still get an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this for populating your reference key.

```
const res = await eventsData.findOne(filter).populate('targetAudience');
```

Visit this link for more clarification https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-populate-method/